# What needs to be changed for websocket security for iOS 10 compatibility

Tags: ios, websocket

We have an iOS Cordova app that was running fine on iOS 9, but on iOS 10 is producing security errors, eg Websocket register error the operation is insecure.

What security requirements has Apple changed/added?

For wss:// and ws:// changes to the CSP, content security policy are required.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've canged my CSP header to the following and it works now:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' gap://ready gap: cdvfile: file: https://ssl.gstatic.com blob: ws: wss:;"/>
```

Edit it to your purpose because it's quite risky to allow everything depending on your usecase.