# Firebase iOS 10 Network Activity Indicator keeps spinning

Tags: firebase, websocket, mobile-safari, ios10

In Safari (sometimes) or full screen web apps (when you add a web page to Home Screen) in iOS 10, when there is a firebase background connection, the status bar network activity indicator keeps spinning forever... in iOS 8 and iOS 9 when Firebase is connected this indicator dissapear, so the users doesn't warn about this small network ussage (websockets), as stated in Apple's UI Guidelines:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/progress-indicators/

> Show this indicator only for network operations lasting more than a
>   few seconds. Don’t display the indicator for quick network operations
>   because it’s likely to disappear before anyone notices its presence or
>   realizes what it’s meant to communicate.

Is there any configuration in Firebase for iOS 10 to avoid this indicator? or it's a bug in the new apple iOS system?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems iOS 10 may have changed something with WebSocket behavior... which may mean we're falling back to long-polling which may explain the network indicator. Could you try adding a CSP to your page like described here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495746/what-needs-to-be-changed-for-websocket-security-for-ios-10-compatibility) and see if that changes the behavior?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I checked with safari developer tools and the iPad connected and yes, it defaults to long pooling, not the normal websocket behavior.

Answer (score 2):

IOS 10 changes the behavior of CSP policies related to websockets.  I added the firebase domain to the connect-src CSP and it worked.  It's not enough to put * in the default-src, I put it without success.
This is the change to my index.html, adding connect-src CSP policy

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src *
'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' data:; default-src *  'unsafe-eval'
'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * wss://*.firebaseio.com 'unsafe-eval'
'unsafe-inline' 'self' ">
```

you could also change only the default-src to connect to any domain with this:

```
default-src * wss://*;
```

in previos iOS (8 & 9) this connect-src was not needed if you use the default-src *.
Thanks Michael Lehenbauer for the "light"